# Flash CS5 to iOS - Using Filesystem causeing app not to run on iPhone

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

So I'm in the final stages of designing a game for the iPhone using Flash CS5 and I'm running into a problem with it running on the iPhone. I am a registered Developer, so I'm doing this completely legit... I'm just doing it on a PC and with Flash so there are a few workarounds being done lol. I'm at a point where it runs perfectly in the simulator but not on the iPhone itself. I load up the game and the opening screen loads up where I have my PLAY button located. The problem is, it doesn't work. It doesn't click, change screens... nada. So I worked it out to be something I'm doing wrong with the way I'm using the Filesystem and my save game file. If I take out the filestream stuff and just put in hard values into all my save game variables, the game runs just fine. The PLAY button does its thing and the game is good to go, except of course that I'm stuck to just the hard set values instead of being able to do little things like change levels. So here is the code I'm using, and hopefully someone can see where I've gone wrong.

The app starts off with running a main.as which calls the saved game file...

```
private function addedMain(event:Event):void {
        //Set up opening screen
        gameStart = new GameStart(this);
        addChild(gameStart);
        //set up the save game info
        _savedGame = new SaveGameFile();
        _savedGame.initGame();
    }
```

gameStart runs a simple script that just has the title screen with a PLAY button. Clicking the PLAY button removes it and loads up the next screen. This is what isn't working right now. The system may be just freezing or something, at this point I don't have a way to tell exactly what's happening except that the PLAY button does nothing. So the next thing called is the saved game file itself:

```
package  {
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.errors.IOError;

public class SaveGameFile extends MovieClip {
    private var file:File;
        private var savedGame:XML;

    public function SaveGameFile() {

    }

    public function initGame():void {
        file = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
        file = file.resolvePath("savedGame.xml");
        xmlLoad();
        initVariables();
    }

    private function xmlLoad():void {
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        try {
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        } catch(e:IOError) {
            createSaveFile();
            xmlSave();
        }
        var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(file.size, File.systemCharset);
        savedGame = XML(str);
        fileStream.close();
    }

    public function saveTheGame():void {
        xmlSave();
    }

    private function xmlSave():void {
        var writeStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        writeStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        var s:String = String(savedGame);
        writeStream.writeMultiByte(s, File.systemCharset);
        writeStream.close();
    }

    private function createSaveFile():void {
        savedGame =
        <savedGame>
            <levelsCompleted>0</levelsCompleted>
            <levelWorkingOn>0</levelWorkingOn>
            <volLevel>0.05</volLevel>
            <sfxLevel>0.75</sfxLevel>
            <level>
                <levelNum>1</levelNum>
                <highScore>0</highScore> //...etc.
            </level>
            //you get the idea
        </savedGame>
    }
```

So as you can see, I'm creating a XML file called savedGame (created the first time the game runs and then is just loaded when the game runs) and from that I'm pulling all my level information as needed and saving scores and such. Again this is working just fine in the simulator (of course) but if I leave this code in, I don't get past the starting page. So does anything jump out to anyone as to why this isn't working? Help! Thanks ;)

Comment: Maybe you should consider making a class that will deal with the saving and loading, which the Flash-produced code will call.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying, but that is what the save game file code listed above is doing. xmlLoad() loads from the saved file and xmlSave() saves it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that you might make a class in objective C, which has the correct API for the iOS filesystem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own a mac or know objective C. I'm working strictly with Actionscript 3 and Flash Pro. So I'm afraid that's not going to work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: You really should reconsider.  You're running xcode somehow (hackintosh?) already, and objective C is a procedural language, easy to learn.

Comment: I'm not using xcode at all. I'm doing this solely on the PC without any mac based programs or SDK at all. I may switch over to mac one day, but I'm almost done with this game... there has to be a way to get this working correctly with the Filesystem Actionscript has created. I just need to find it... lol.

Comment: Something is probably throwing an error somewhere. I would try creating a TextField on stage and just litter the code with logging statements that go into that. If that doesn't work, perhaps try saving using a SharedObject instead of writing to a file?

Comment: Use "Notepad++" convert the file to "UTF-8 Without BOM" Save changes You don't need the "fix code" that you wrote because this solves the bad chars Good luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: So I may have been on the wrong track all along because through messing around with my file on my computer I was finally able to see the error occur where I could easily trace problems compared to tracing on the iPhone. I don't know if my original code was flawed or not, however, I do know that this code below works perfectly, so I'm keeping it (and I like it better anyway). HOWEVER, my main problem seems to have been the fact that I'm using XML as my save file. This is perfectly fine to do, BUT for some reason, saving the file causes a couple of strange characters to be entered at the very beginning of the file. So instead of starting

```
<savedGame>
```

it was starting with something like

```
|Y<savedGame>
```

The | was actually a symbol I couldn't find that had a line in the middle and a charCode of 25 and the Y was actually a Yen sign. So whatever that was, it was causing me to get a 1088 Error. I solved this by striping any and all characters (whatever they end up being just in case it's different for everyone... not sure if it is but not taking any chances). So in my code below I added a section between //EDIT START and //EDIT STOP that is only needed if you too are using XML in your script. Otherwise you can leave this out. Hope this helps :)

ORIGINAL POST: OK so it seems that through some messing around with the code listed at the bottom of the page linked by danii, I was able to get that sites code working after all. I'm tempted to look back at my original code and mess with it to see if I can get it to work with what I've learned from this, but the game is working so I'm moving on and never looking back... lol. What I did find out though is that for my needs, that pages code was not quite workable (and why I gave up on it originally). It might have worked for their needs, but unless you package the game with a file, as far as I can tell their function "getSaveStream" will always return 'null' because the file will never be able to be written. So I removed a lot of their if's and try's because they were causing the game to fail. Here is what I ended up with in the context of my original post:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.errors.IOError;

    public class SaveGameFile extends MovieClip {
        private var f:File;
        private var savedGame:XML;

        public function SaveGameFile() {

        }

        public function initGame():void {
            xmlLoad();
            initVariables();
        }

        private function getSaveStream(write:Boolean, sync:Boolean = true):FileStream {
            // The data file lives in the app storage directory, per iPhone guidelines.
            f = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("savedGame.xml");

            // Try creating and opening the stream.
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            try {
                //write is True and writing asynchronously.
                if(write && !sync) {
                    fs.openAsync(f, FileMode.WRITE);
                } else {
                    //For synchronous write, or all reads, open synchronously.
                    fs.open(f, write ? FileMode.WRITE : FileMode.READ);
                }
            } catch(e:Error) {
                // On error return null.
                return null;
            }
            return fs;
        }

        private function xmlLoad():void {
            var fs:FileStream = getSaveStream(false);
            if(fs) {
                var str:String = fs.readMultiByte(f.size, File.systemCharset);
                //EDIT START
                //check for "bad characters" at the start of the XML file
                var badCharCheck = str.charCodeAt(0);
                //the first char MUST be '<' which has a CharCode of 60
                while(badCharCheck != 60) {
                    //if the first character isn't '<' then remove it
                    str = str.replace(String.fromCharCode(badCharCheck), "") ;
                    //recheck the first character
                    badCharCheck = str.charCodeAt(0);
                }
                //EDIT END
                savedGame = XML(str);
                fs.close();
            } else {
            //fs returned null so create the XML file savedGame and save it
                createSaveFile();
                xmlSave();
            }
        }

        public function saveTheGame():void {
            //this is used to call the save function externally
            xmlSave();
        }

        private function xmlSave():void {
            //the file exists because it was created with FileMode.WRITE in getSaveStream
            var fs:FileStream = getSaveStream(true, false);
            var s:String = String(savedGame);
            fs.writeUTF(s);
            fs.close();
        }

        private function createSaveFile():void {
            //this is only called the very first time the game is run on the iPhone
            savedGame =
                <savedGame>
                    <levelsCompleted>0</levelsCompleted>
                    <levelWorkingOn>0</levelWorkingOn>
                    <volLevel>0.05</volLevel>
                    <sfxLevel>0.75</sfxLevel>
                    <level>
                        <levelNum>1</levelNum>
                        <highScore>0</highScore> //...etc.
                    </level>
                    //you get the idea
                </savedGame>
        }
```

So I'm happy to say it tested perfectly and is now running and saving information like it is supposed to. Hope this is of use to someone who runs into the same issue I did. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. Though my original code may have actually been working. It seems my use of XML needed extra help in order to work due to some quirk with the way XML and Flash work. Oh well, working 100% now.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe a while ago published a few articles on programming AIR apps for iOs devices, maybe this one will help you out (in the unlikely case you didn't see it already):

[Saving state in AIR applications for iOS devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/saving_state_air_apps.html)

Comment: I did see that thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help. Even went through it again but I'm still getting stuck in the same place.

Comment: OK I gave up on their code too soon it seems. It does work... see my answer.